# Pivot in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have table like this;

```
Date        PlacementName    campaignID   Impressions   Clicks   TotalConversions  Activity

01/01/2014    USA             100           5000          500        50        Mobile Book
01/02/2014    U.K             101           7000          250        30        Mobile Book
01/01/2014    USA             100           9000          800        40        Mobile TV
01/02/2014    U.K             101           6000          300        10        Mobile TV
```

I want to pivot table for 15-20 Activity from the real table because this is just example table.

I want my table look like below;

```
Date         PlacementName     CampaignID    Impressions    Clicks   Mobile Book  Mobile TV
01/01/2014    USA              100           5000           500       50           NULL
01/01/2014    U.K              100           9000           800       NULL         40
01/02/2014    USA              101           7000           250       30           NULL
01/02/2014    U.K              101           6000           300       NULL         10
```

This is the format I want in final table. I want to write query for this table.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What research have you done? Have you made any attempts to solve your problem?

Comment: Have a look at sql count and group by

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO : if you cant give answer please don't downgrade my points. I am very new to this environment and if don't want to help dont help sir but don't downgrade my reputation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you, we need some minimum information. Once you provide this information, I'll be happy to reverse the downvote.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: And for your answer sir, I have tried some tactics to solve this , but didn't able to find out how to do that because I am doing this first time and have to finish before time. Thanks for your help. I am using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: @gerrytan: Thanks for your advise and I am going to try that then will let you know what results will come. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the result would be to use an aggregate function along with a CASE expression to convert the rows of data into columns, but you could also apply the PIVOT function.

```
select date,
  placementname,
  campaignid,
  impressions,
  clicks,
  sum(case when activity = 'Mobile Book' then TotalConversions else 0 end) MobileBook,
  sum(case when activity = 'Mobile TV' then TotalConversions else 0 end) MobileTV
from yourtable
group by date, placementname, campaignid, impressions, clicks;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48ef7b/1)

```
select date, placementname, 
  campaignid, impressions,
  clicks,
  [Mobile Book], [Mobile TV]
from
(
  select date, placementname,
    campaignid, impressions,
    clicks, activity, totalconversions
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  sum(totalconversions)
  for activity in ([Mobile Book], [Mobile TV])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48ef7b/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir your solution did work perfectly for me. Thank you so much. However, I have tried first one because second one I did try already but the result came with error. Thanks again.

Comment: @ADBI: are you familiar with accepting answers? I don't think you've accepted any in your profile, but it looks like you've commented a couple of times to say that something did work. To "accept", click on the tick icon to the left of the appropriate answer, so that it turns green. It will give you a point or two I think, and more importantly it thanks a helpful person.